# Как вывести количество юзеров у которых есть группы в определенном отрезке времени

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

Собственно говоря есть категория юзеров $participants, которые состоят в группах и нет, у групп есть время начала $start_time и конца $end_time , нужно вывести count тех юзеров которые состоят в группах по определенному dateRange, я не знаю как написать последнее условие и как связать dateRange к юзерам, ведь это параметры groups.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Group;
use app\Participants;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class ParticipantCounts extends Controller
{
  public function ParticipantCountsWithGroups()
  {
    $participants = $Participants::has('groups')->get();


        $dateRange = "DD.MM.YY-DD.MM.YY";
        $splitTimeStamp = explode("-", $dateRange);
        $start_time = $splitTimeStamp[0];
        $end_time = $splitTimeStamp[1];

        Carbon::parse($start_time)->format('Y-m-d');
        Carbon::parse($end_time)->format('Y-m-d');

        $participants->where(function($query))
        {
          $query->where('start_time')->whereBetween('end_time'[$])

        }
}
}
```

[image: Схема таблиц]

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте запостил простенькую схему таблиц/миграций, потому что лично у меня сходу понимание вопроса не возникло после прочтения текста )) Извините если не по теме :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, есть две модели - `Participant` и `Group`. У групп есть поля для начала и конца периода, и модели уже связаны методом `groups`. Тогда должна сработать такая конструкция:

```
$participants = Participant::whereHas('groups', function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time){
                    $q->where('start_time', '>', $start_time)->where('end_time', '<', $end_time);
                })->get();
```